# Automatically detect identical consecutive std::string::find() calls

Tags: c++, regex, pcre, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

During a code review, i found source code like this:

```
void f_odd(std::string &className, std::string &testName)
{
   if (className.find("::") != std::string::npos)
   {
     testName = className.substr(className.find("::") + 2);
     (void)className.erase(className.find("::"), std::string::npos);
   }
}
```

Within this function, std::string::find() is called three times with the same pattern( here "::").

This code can of course be refactored to

```
void f(std::string &className, std::string &testName)
{
   const size_t endOfClassNamePos = className.find("::");
   if (endOfClassNamePos != std::string::npos)
   {
     testName = className.substr(endOfClassNamePos + 2);
     (void)className.erase(endOfClassNamePos, std::string::npos);
   }
}
```

where find is called only once.

**Question**

Does anybody know a strategy to detecting such a pattern like this? I am having a huge code base, where i intend to spot this pattern.
I plan to use a Windows or a Linux environment.

**Potential Strategies**

1. Use/adapt a static code analysis tool, like cppcheck to detect these kind of oddities.
2. Search within the code base with regular expression.
3. Use/adapt clang-tidy for detection of this pattern.
4. Write a custom checker in some language (e.g. Python) that detects these issues. In this case, the checking should be performed on pre-processed code.

**No Go's**

- Manual review

---

**Update 1**

I decided to start with potential strategy 1). I plan to adapt cppcheck to catch this issue.

Cppcheck offers a possibility to write customized rules, based on PCRE regular expressions. For this, cppcheck has to be compiled with enabled PCRE support. Since the current test environment is Linux-based, the following commands can be used to download the latest version of cppcheck:

`git clone https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck.git && cd cppcheck`

After that, compile and install the tool as follows:

`sudo make install HAVE_RULES=yes`

Now the basic tool setup is done. In order to develop a cppcheck-rule, i prepared a simple test case (file: test.cpp), similar to the sample code in the first section of this article. This file contains three functions and the cppcheck-rule shall emit a warning on `f_odd` and `f_odd1` about consecutive identical `std::string::find` calls.

test.cpp:

```
#include <string>
void f(std::string &className, std::string &testName)
{
   const size_t endOfClassNamePos = className.find("::");
   if (endOfClassNamePos != std::string::npos)
   {
     testName = className.substr(endOfClassNamePos + 2);
     (void)className.erase(endOfClassNamePos, std::string::npos);
   }
 }

 void f_odd(std::string &className, std::string &testName)
 {
    if (className.find("::") != std::string::npos)
    {
       testName = className.substr(className.find("::") + 2);
       (void)className.erase(className.find("::"), std::string::npos);
    }
 }

 #define A "::"
 #define B "::"
 #define C "::"
 void f_odd1(std::string &className, std::string &testName)
 {
   if (className.find(A) != std::string::npos)
   {
      testName = className.substr(className.find(B) + 2);
      (void)className.erase(className.find(C), std::string::npos);
   }
 }
```

So far so good. Now cppcheck has to be tweaked to catch consecutive identical `std::string::find` calls. For this i have created a [cppcheck_rule-file](https://github.com/orbitcowboy/cppcheck_rules/blob/master/rules/rule.xml) that contains a regular expression that matches consecutive identical `std::string::find` calls:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rule>
<tokenlist>normal</tokenlist>
<pattern><![CDATA[([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\s*\.\s*find)(\s*\(\s*\"[ -~]*\"\s*\))[ -\{\n]*(\1\2\3)+[ -z\n]]]></pattern>
<message>
    <severity>style</severity>
    <summary>Found identical consecutive std::string::find calls.</summary>
</message>
```

This file can be used to extend cppcheck about a new check. 
Lets try:

`cppcheck --rule-file=rules/rule.xml test/test.cpp`

and the output is

```
Checking test/test.cpp...
[test/test.cpp:14]: (style) Found identical consecutive std::string::find calls.
[test/test.cpp:26]: (style) Found identical consecutive std::string::find calls.
```

Now, identical consecutive `std::string::find` calls can be detected in C/C++ codes. Does anybody know a better/more efficient or more clever solution?

References:

- [Checkout the cppcheck_rule file on github](https://github.com/orbitcowboy/cppcheck_rules)
- [How to write custom rules for cppcheck](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwjPSrm7LMAhXMWSwKHX66BH8QFgg_MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.kent.edu%2F~rothstei%2Fspring_12%2Fsecprognotes%2Fcppcheck_writing-rules-1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFLjfvbJ4NlmqatgOg6TeJ7te2knw&sig2=Cn3z2MZMLH4f1jqOTPa-Og)

---

Comment: You could write your own [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) check to detect this.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you clang-tidy is another potentia tool that could do the job. I'll update my potential solutions section.

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question such that it doesn't appear like a request for tool recommendations? These are [explicitly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: I haven't checked out how `cppcheck` applies your rule, but you might want to create some test cases to make sure you don't get false positives: where the `string` is mutated between `find` calls (so the previous result can't be reused), where the calls happen in different functions, where different scopes have same-named `string`s being searched....

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with such a tool is that a lexical analysis can only check if there is *textual* repetition. Taking your example, calling `className.find("::")` twice is a potential issue if the variable refers to the same string twice. But let me add one *small* change to your code: `className = className.substr(className.find("::") + 2);`. Suddenly the meaning of the next `className.find` has changed *dramatically*.

Can you find such changes? You need a full-blown compiler for that, and even then you have to be pessimistic. Sticking to your example, could `className` be changed via an iterator? It's not just direct manipulation you need to be aware of.

Is there no positive news? Well: existing compilers do have a similar mechanism. It's called Common Subexpression Elimination, and it works conceptually as you would want it to work in the example above. But that is also bad news in one way: If the situation is detectable, it's unimportant because it's already optimized out by the compiler!